# Azure PowerShell 1.0 - Where is Get-AzureSBNamespace?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I've been following this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/12/01/how-to-create-a-service-bus-namespace-and-an-event-hub-using-a-powershell-script.aspx) to create a Service Bus namespace on Azure using PowerShell 1.0. However, after logging into Azure using the cmdlet `Login-AzureRmAccount` (as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)) and attempting to use the cmdlet `Get-AzureSBNamespace` returns a null reference exception, i.e.,

`Get-AzureSBNamespace : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619274.aspx) for Powershell 1.0, there appears to be no reference to any cmdlets for the Service Bus services on Azure, i.e., `Get-AzureSBNamespace`.

Does Azure PowerShell 1.0 support Azure Service Bus (specifically EventHubs)?

Comment: you're mixing ASM and ARM cmdlets... the SB ones still reside in the ASM cmdlets (so thats plan verb-AZURENoun, the ARM ones are verb-AZUREMnoun). for that you need to login with add-azureaccount and then use them. if not possible to ue them first do an import-module Azure

Comment: note, to ceate eventhub matters you need to address the SDK in the easiest way of doing it : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/12/01/how-to-create-a-service-bus-namespace-and-an-event-hub-using-a-powershell-script.aspx

Comment: Looged in using `Add-AzureAccount` and all works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following link to create Service Bus Event hub and created it succesfully.

As mentioned in the above comments you cant assign an event hub to a resouce group it comes under Add-Azure Account cmd.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-powershell-how-to-provision/